# How to get the session details from sql server database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4, session, session-management

I have one Solution which has different projects like ASP.Net 
    and ASP.Net MVC in this solution. When the user logs in to the 
    application, the same credentials I need to pass to the other project 
    in same solution. It should not ask credentials again, because he has
    already logged in. For that I have stored the session details in the sql 
    server database using the SqlServer mode. But the problem is I am unable
    to get the session which is stored in the database. 
    Any help on this will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

This is what i have tried to fetch data from ASPState database

```
public ActionResult Home()
    {
        ViewBag.Result =Session["username"].ToString();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select SessionId from 
         ASPStateTempSessions", con);

        byte[] bytdata = new byte[50];
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        var list = new List<LoginUser>();
        if(dr.HasRows)
        {
            while(dr.Read())
            {
                //obj=dr["SessionId"];
                string obj = dr["SessionId"].ToString();
                bytdata = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(obj);
                System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(bytdata);
                    BinaryFormatter bin = new BinaryFormatter();
                    //bin.Serialize(ms, bytdata);
                    //list = (List<LoginUser>)bin.Deserialize(ms);

                    string session = Convert.ToString(bin.Deserialize(ms));
            }
        }
        ViewBag.Data = list;
        return View();
    }
```

This is what i have configured ion Web.config

```
 <sessionState mode="SQLServer" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="SessionSqlCon" cookieless="false" timeout="10" />
  </providers>
</sessionState>
```

Comment: I have added code for your reference Mr. HuangChen..

Comment: Why aren't you using ASP.NET's session API? Why are you trying to query the database directly? ASP.NET will load the proper session in memory and recognize the user *automatically* by checking the cookies it set during logon. If it doesn't, your application isn't set correctly.

Comment: help me out by uploading sample code, please